# How to pass the item's value into array or list while sending the POST request in Python?

Tags: python, json, request

```
import requests
import json
import urllib2
data = '{"userId":"faraz@wittyparrot.com","password":"73-rRWk_"}'
response = requests.post(url, data=data,  headers=
{"ContentType":"application/json"})
dataa =  json.loads(response.content)
a = dataa['accessToken']
print a
tiketId = a['tokenType'] + a['tokenValue']
print tiketId
wit = '{ "name": "wit along with the attachment","parentId": "6d140705-c178-4410-bac3-b15507a5415e",  "content": "faraz khan wit", "desc": "This is testing of Authorization wit","note": "Hello auto wit"}'
response = requests.post(URLcreatewit, data=wit , headers={"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":tiketId} )
createwit =  json.loads(response.content)
print createwit
Id = createwit['id']
WitId = Id
print WitId
```

so here witId is 2d81dc7e-fc34-49d4-b4a7-39a8179eaa55 that comes as response
now i want to use that witId into below json as a input:

```
Sharewit = '{ "contentEntityIds":["'+WitId+'"],"userEmailIds": ["ediscovery111@gmail.com"],"permission":{"canComment": false,"canRead": true,"canEditFolderAndWits": false,"canFurtherShare": false,"canEditWits": false}, "inherit":true}'
response = requests.post(URLcreatewit, data= Sharewit , headers={"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":tiketId} )
print response.status_code
```

so in the last json, it seems it does not take the value of witId and gives 400 status error

Comment: Can anyone help me please......

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the similar thing and Here is how I have done.

Assuming the rest api responds with a Json Object.

```
id = response.json()["id"]
```

However if the response is a Json Array
Looped in through the array and got the ids appended to an array

```
item = []
for item in response.json():
    ids.append(item["id")
```

Also, I have used a Json Object - to be able to change values.
Instead of creating it as Json String.

```
sharewit["userEmailIds"] = ["ediscovery111@gmail.com"]
sharewit["contentEntityIds"] = [id]

response = requests.post(URLcreatewit, data=json.dumps(sharewit), headers={"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":tiketId} )
```